# How come inserting a node in a heap takes 1+lgN compares. From where did that 1 came from?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue, heap

[image]
Here, 91 is being added to the heap, so 91 will be compared with 36 then with 89 and finally with 90 so total compares are 3 = lg8. So what was the reason of adding 1 in utmost number of compares when you are inserting an element in the heap?

Comment: *"Adding 1 in utmost number of compares"*: Please add a quote of -- and reference to -- the source that states this.

Comment: (The decimal logarithm of 8 is smaller than one. 3 is the binary logarithm of 8 - log₂ or ld.)

Comment: Hi trincot , I am learning dsa from a course named Algorithms part 1 by princeton university on coursera. In that course in the binary heap video it is written that the Cost of insertion in a heap is at most 1+lgN compares. Also Robert Sedgewick the instructor of the course said in the video that "And notice since it's just going form bottom to top in the heap, it takes at most 1 plus log base 2 of N compares."

Comment: Can you link to your source? BTW, the `dsa` tag is about something entirely different.

Comment: Here's the source
https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1/lecture/Uzwy6/binary-heaps at 6:24  
And my bad, in my college dsa means data structure and algorithms :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify the claim, the exact context is crucial, but the edge case can be explained as follows:

Before insertion of node 91, the binary heap is *perfect*:

```
        __90__
       /      \
     89        70
    /  \      /  \
  36    75  63    65
```

It has 7 nodes, so *N* is 7. The *floored* base-2 logarithm of *N* is 2 in this case.

When inserting 91, there are 3 comparisons needed to restore the heap property. So in this particular case we have that the number of comparisons is indeed 1+<sub>⌊</sub>log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub><sub>⌋</sub>. This is a worst case scenario, and assumes that  is the number of nodes *before* insertion takes place.

If  is defined as the number of nodes *after* the insertion, or the original tree is not *perfect*, then the additional 1 is not needed in that formula.

Comment: Thanks you for answering, I was treating ⌊log2⌋7 equivalent to 3. I didn't knew we need to take the floored value and yes we need to take N as the number of nodes before insertion takes place.